# Помогите пожалуйста cинхронизировать select между собой

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Нужно на чистом js чтобы select синхронизировался с другим селект, как в примере

```js
var $synch = $(".synch").on('change', function() {
  $synch.not(this).get(0).selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
});
```

```html
<select class="synch">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<select class="synch">
  <option value="A">AA</option>
  <option value="B">BB</option>
  <option value="C">CC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Не вижу с чем помогать (попытка переписать отсутствует) - вижу "мне нужно но лень изучать/пробовать, сделайте копипаст-решение".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let synch = document.querySelectorAll('.synch').forEach((element, index, array) => {
    element.addEventListener('change', function(){
            index > 0 ? array[0].value = this.value : array[1].value = this.value
    })
});
```

Но это конкретно под

```
<select class="synch">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<select class="synch">
  <option value="A">AA</option>
  <option value="B">BB</option>
  <option value="C">CC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: А если в select классы разные будут ?

Comment: @ИльяМельник 
`let synch = document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach((element, index, array) => {
    element.addEventListener('change', function(){
            index > 0 ? array[0].value = this.value : array[1].value = this.value
    })
});`
Бро можно так:) главное что в значение value:)